# Contact system database design

Tags: database-design

I'm designing a database for contacts and I'm looking for some feedback on the current design.

What I want:

- A contact can be a person or an organization.
- A contact can have many groups.
- A contact can have many emails and addresses
- A contact can have one organization (employed)
- An organization can have many contacts (employees)
- A group can have many contacts.

What I have:

- Contact(**Id**, PersonId (FK), OrganizationId (FK), EmployerId (FK, self reference))
- Person(**Id**, FirstName, LastName, Birthday)
- Organization(**Id**, Name, Founded)
- Group(**Id**, Name)
- ContactGroup(**Id**, ContactId (FK), GroupId (FK))
- Email(**Id**, ContactId (FK), Name)
- Address(**Id**, ContactId (FK), Street, City, ZipCode, Country)

What bothers me the most is that the contact entity has one organization or one person, and also a self reference (EmployerId) if an organization has employees (which are also contact entities) and vice versa.

[image]

Is this a problem or see you a better way?

Comment: Take a look on 'The Data Model Resource Book' by Len Silverston. Party-role-relationship approach perfectly fits your task...

Answer (score -1):

Check the "Data Model Resource Book, Vol. 1". It covers standard schemata for - among other things - contact management. Pretty much the whole CRM and accounting etc. side.

And yes, there are a lot of problems with your approach - but I wont replicate 30 pages or so from that book describing all the issues.

Comment: @M_Griffiths Can you suggest anything?